# How to run ssd_resnet_50_fpn_coco network from Tensorflow's Object Detection API in cv2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

I have been using tensorflow's [1.x Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1.md) to train custom object detection models. I like to run these models using cv2, since I already have cv2 available in the inference environment. The particular model that I'm struggling with is the **ssd_resnet_50_fpn_coco**, which can be found in the [model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md#tensorflow-1-detection-model-zoo).

To run inference on a model from tensorflow's object detection API using cv2 I need two files, a **frozen_inference_graph.pb** and a **graph.pbtxt** as described [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API), on openCV's wiki page.
The **frozen_inference_graph.pb** can be created using the API's [exportation script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/exporting_models.md), which takes in three checkpoint files (.ckpt) and a configuration file (.config). The **graph.pbtxt** can be created using the *tf_text_graph_ssd.py* script provided [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API#generate-a-config-file).

when I run the *tf_text_graph_ssd.py* script, pointed at the **frozen_inference_graph.pb** from the model zoo I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_text_graph_ssd.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tf_text_graph_common import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf_text_graph_common'
```

I fix this by copying the [tf_text_graph_common.py](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/tf_text_graph_common.py) script to the execution folder, as suggested [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/210958/tf_text_graph_ssdpy-no-module-named-tf_text_graph_common/). This makes the script run and produce a working graph.pbtxt.

Now this works just fine if I use one of the pre-trained **frozen_inference_graph.pb** file from tensorflow's model zoo, to generate the **graph.pbtxt** file. However, if I use tensorflow's exportation script on the corresponding .ckpt files provided in the model zoo, to create a **frozen_inference_graph.pb**, then the *tf_text_graph_ssd.py* script fails with the following error:

```
Levels: [3-7]
Anchor scale: 4.000000
Scales per octave: 2
Aspect ratios: [1.0, 2.0, 0.5]
Number of classes: 90
Number of layers: 5
box predictor: weight_shared_convolutional
Input image size: 640x640
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_text_graph_ssd.py", line 413, in <module>
    createSSDGraph(args.input, args.config, args.output)
  File "tf_text_graph_ssd.py", line 235, in createSSDGraph
    assert(graph_def.node[0].op == 'Placeholder')
AssertionError
```

When I search for the error I find this closed github [page](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/18380).
I would really like to get this to work, so any help is greatly appreciated

My installation:
kubuntu 20.04
python 3.6.10
tensorflow 1.15.5
libprotoc 3.6.1
opencv-python 4.5.3.56

tensorflow object detection API commit:
b6bb00b4e0e59dfcd2b4b6d307275d3fca14a933 (latest master Mon Sep 6 10:41:53 2021)